# Mysql stop slave at log position

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to re-dump a MySQL table from a master to its slave.

Can I

1. stop the slave
2. create a dump of the table I want with --single-transaction --master-flag to take note of its log position
3. start the slave, **but have it stop once it reaches that log position**
4. apply the dump to replace the table
5. start the slave again normally

How can I do step 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you stop your slave, you can specify the positions you want to process up to in your `START SLAVE` statement.  Something like:

```
START SLAVE UNTIL MASTER_LOG_FILE='xxxxx', MASTER_LOG_POS=yyyyyy;
```

Documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/start-slave.html).